# Grid view image source issue

Tags: android

i am trying to send an array containing strings of url of the image source to the imageadapter of the grid view. But only the last url of the array is being used to set the image in the adapter. some help here would be appreciated.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ImageAdapter imageListAdapter = null;
    for( int inx = 0 ; inx < imageUrl.length ; inx++)
        {
                 imageListAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context,imageUrl[inx],productName[inx] );
                 System.out.println(imageUrl[inx]);
                 System.out.println(productName[inx]);
                 gridview.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);
        }
```

adapter code :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
static int i = 0;
String url = null;
String name = null;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, String url , String name ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.url = url;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCount() {
    // return url.length;
    return ++i;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialise some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    //Bitmap bmp  = loadBitmap("http://www.xvr.com/aero/planes/boeing/boeingf15.jpg");

    Bitmap bmp  = loadBitmap(url);
    System.out.println("in adapter :"+url);
    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return imageView;
}
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),  4 * 1024);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream,  4 * 1024);

        int byte_;
        while ((byte_ = in.read()) != -1)
            out.write(byte_);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("","Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }catch( IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Comment: can u put your code too?

Comment: Try adding some of your adapter code here. Kind of hard to debug if we can't read code.

Comment: what mean's last url of array

Comment: last element in the array containing urls

Comment: can you present constructor code of adapter

Comment: it takes in context and two strings

Comment: THe complete adapter code is as above

Comment: I have edited my answer check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating new ImageAdapter every time in your for loop and setting it to Gridview so in the last iteration of your loop the last image is set to adapter and finally that adapter is set to gridview.

**Note:** Your implementation is wrong have look at following example http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views and search for keyword `GridView`

Pass url and name as string array just once rather than each time creating new object of ImageAdapter something like below, and change your adapter code accordingly.

```
imageListAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context,imageUrl,productName);
```

Comment: I did pass the array of url and name , but i was unable to return the image view in getview

Comment: That is because u are downloading images in getview I would suggest to first download all images create an array of that images and pass that and do not download the image Ui thread but do it in another background thread google for it you will find many references for that